# How to find out PCI devices in Debian without pciutils?

Tags: linux, debian, pci

I tried to update a Server running Debian Etch but something went wrong while updating the kernel, so we decided to reinstall Debian via CD. Before doing that, I have to find out which drivers are needed in this fresh installation (it has some type of PCI Audio recording card) and found

```
# apt-get install pciutils
# lspci
```

should work ([here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/305/Finding_out_basic_information_about_your_hardware) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/349733/how-to-tell-which-devices-are-in-a-pci-slot)). Unfortunately the corrupted kernel won't let me install new software (theres a dependency problem with libc, me and some oher guys tried everything to fix it).

So what I'm asking for: Is there any other way to show details of connected PCI devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: use a live distro (Ubuntu), and issue the relevant commands (lspci, lshw, hwinfo, dmidecode...) from there, You will get the same info as if running your very own Debian Etch.

Just a question: Since you have to re-install, why not move up to Wheezy?

Comment: Aaaaw, why didn't I came up with this myself :) Thanks! Upgrading to wheezy was the plan, when I said updating I meant upgrading.